# Why isn't the unity launcher shown using nxserver nomachine?

Tags: 12.04, unity, nx

I am using ubuntu 12.04  and recently installed nxserver, nxclient and nxnode on my office machine and laptop. When I am trying to access my office machine from my laptop, I am able to see all the items on the desktop, however it does not show me the launcher panel. and thus I can't do anything. When I open a text file in gedit, there is no  "close, minimize and resize panel" on the top of text window. I have been trying since this morning but failed miserably.

Why isn't the launcher visible?

Comment: I think I have the exact same problem. I'm running 3.5